# JavaScript: How to filter object into list of keys where nested property meets condition?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, filter, lodash

How can I filter an object into an array of keys matching a particular condition on nested object values. For example if I want to filter the following

```
let object = {
  'key1': {
    'value': 'one'
   },
  'key2': {
    'value': 'two'
   },
  'key3': {
    'value': 'two'
   }
}
```

by children that have `'value': 'two'` to produce

```
['key2', 'key3']
```

how might I achieve this.

Comment: does the structure have always a `value` property? what have you tried?

Comment: The reason your question is getting downvoted is that you do not show a research effort. There are already loads of this type of questions answered on SO.

Comment: Yes, it will always have a 'value' property. Currently I am using Lodash's _.filter and Object.values: 
```_.filter(Object.values(object), function (o) {return o.value === value})``` I do not like this approach as it brings along the entire child object instead of just the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want to take the objects keys and filter them:

```
 Object.keys(object).filter(key => object[key].value === "two")
```